# Is HMAC frequently implemented wrong?

Tags: rest, security, authentication, hmac

Some REST services I've encountered required that I download an API key or some kind of shared secret, and simply pass this in with the headers.

But when trying to describe this design pattern in a Google search, all I get is "HMAC" which appears to be more sophisticated; HMAC is designed to never send the shared secret directly to the server, and involves hashing the secret key with other data.

So what am I looking at? Is there a name for it?

Comment: IINM, if it's ("API key", "shared secret" or "server key") passed in headers, it's used for _Authorization_ (to access an API), not unlike a "password" more than likely sent HTTPS. Keys/shared secrets used to _sign, or generate tokens_ aren't exposed nor passed in headers - it's used on both sides to generate and verify some "message" (e.g. expected sender, intended receiver, "sanctity" of data - making sure it wasn't tampered with in transport, etc.)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, using an API key in the way you describe is not HMAC.  It is often referred to as "API Key Authentication" or some similar name.  API key authentication is simply a password that is passed, usually as a header, along with every request.

This is only secure when paired with HTTPS, so that anyone watching the traffic can't simply read out the API key.